# Is there a way to see the list of solved questions?

Tags: support

I like to read how questions are solved and learn the method, so it would be nice to see the list of solved questions. Is there a way to do this?

Edit:

I assume the downvote came from my lack of research effort, so I am going to enumerate websites that could have helped to answer my question.

Though I have to admit that I did almost no research before asking other than googling "stack overflow solved questions" which was unsuccessful.

Nevertheless, the accepted answer below provided a very helpful insight which I could not find through this search.

1. [How do I search](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching): I should have seen this first.
2. [How to find answered questions on Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201911/how-to-find-answered-questions-on-stackoverflow/201914)

Comment: By solved do you mean post with an accepted answer? You can use "isaccepted:yes".

Comment: @ArcticChar Ah yes, I meant that. Thank you! If you don't mind, you can turn it to an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: I was going to mention that there are also solved questions, with no accepted answers (after checking the filter to sort questions), but it's seems that the filter doesn't work as expected. I was expecting all questions with  not accepted answer(s), but it returned both: questions with not accepted answer(s) and questions with no answers. And it seems like a bug because there's another specific option to sort questions by "no answer".

Comment: Accepted answers are not necessarily *better* than not accepted answers, Kaira.  Popularity, rep, popular vote, exposure, determines what is accepted, but not so much does it reflect *the best answer* orcorrectness of an answer, and many times all answers are correct, and many times askers fail to accept an answer.  So if you want to see only checkmarked answers, your have no reason to believe they are the best answes

Comment: ...and for questions with no accept vote, your blocking yourself completely from seeing excellent solutions to many problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [search tools](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) on MSE offer a large range of options which can serve to filter search results.  Per the comments above, you *can* use the search flag `isaccepted:yes`, but this is going to narrow your results only to those questions which have accepted answers.  There are two major pitfalls with this approach:

1. When an asker accepts an answer, they are indicating that the answer is the one which helped them the most (or, really, they are indicated that they "like" that answer the most).  This does not mean that the answer is correct, or that there are not "more correct" answers—it only indicates that the original asker liked the answer better than the others, for whatever reason (with one of the possible reasons being "no other answers had been provided at the time the answer was accepted").  By focusing on accepted answers, you are limiting the scope of your search to those questions which have answers fancied by the original asker.
2. Many askers *never* accept an answer.  There are innumerable excellent answers on this site which have never been accepted (again, for who knows what reason).  If you focus on questions with accepted answers, you are going to miss out on these answers.

Instead, I would suggest that you focus on questions with answers.  For example, add `answers:m..n` (where $m$ and $n$ are either integers or blank) to a query in order to find posts with between $m$ and $n$ answers (inclusive, e.g. `answers:2..` returns questions with $2$ or more answers).  Or you can add `score:5` to locate posts with a net score of $5$ or more (highly upvoted questions are more likely to have good answers).  The search flag `is:answer` can also help you to focus on answers.