# About a filter that returns questions with no answers and questions with answers but not accepted, at the same time.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

I noticed, after checking [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33382/), that when one uses the Filter to find questions with not accepted answer(s) returns both: questions with no answers and questions with not accepted answers.

For example, in the following picture returned both: question without accepted answer and question without answer.

[image]

While the output is logically correct, I think this wasn't the actual expected output. Notice the first section of the Filter *Filter by* ´No answers´ and ´No accepted answers´, I think that the later is supposed to filter out just the ones with answer(s) but not accepted. And the former is supposed to return questions with no answer(s).
These two  options are  matching on the ´no answer(s)´ and I think they should not be matching.

Although this can be mend by using the techniques mentioned [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33385).

Comment: I  think you need to filter the search more: answered questions without an accepted answer.

Comment: How can a question have an accepted answer if it has no answers?

Comment: This is by design.  A question with no answers *is* a question with no accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design.  A question with answers, none of which are accepted, has no accepted answers.  A question with no answers also has no accepted answers.  Hence a search for questions with no accepted answers should find both kinds of questions.

Comment: I don't think this was the purpose of the filter.

Comment: @Verónica It is the purpose. It's worth mentioning that, until recently, these filters were part of drop down menus rather than check boxes, so the query on the back end is designed to be inclusive, not exclusive - you couldn't use more than one, so it was assumed that, in general, people want all questions that don't have an accepted answer not merely the subset of answered questions that don't have one of those answers accepted.